# Starting VirtualBox VM using Python

Tags: python, virtualbox

How can I start a virtual machine from virtualbox as *headless* using **`pyvb`** modules?

Answer (score 11):

You can use the real python bindings instead (and not a wrapper that call the VBoxManager command line in a subprocess, say pyvb) relatively easily by using the [vboxshell.py](http://www.virtualbox.org/svn/vbox/trunk/src/VBox/Frontends/VBoxShell/vboxshell.py) script from virtual box.

Or you can use it for reference documentation of the python bindings. There's no documentation for the python bindings and honestly they are not implemented in a good pythonic way. Attributes and methods are not present in the `__dict__`, so it's not possible to find them by introspection (or autocompletion in ipython) and there's no docstring either. Another reference for the python bindings are the source code of the [vboxweb](http://code.google.com/p/vboxweb/) project here: [VBoxWebSrv.py](http://code.google.com/p/vboxweb/source/browse/trunk/VBoxWebSrv.py)

For the headless startup, you need to pass 'headless' to the third argument (type) of the vbox.openRemoteSession(session, uuid, type, "") method call. Look at startVm() function in vboxshell.py and VBoxWebSrv.py for reference.

Answer (score 0):

YOu can use the `pyvbox` python module to startup and stop virtualboxes using the Vbox interaface:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyvbox

Answer (score 0):

If you use the library [pyvbox](https://pypi.org/project/pyvbox/) the task you want to achieve is very simple:

```
import virtualbox

vbox = virtualbox.VirtualBox()
machine = vbox.find_machine("you_virtual_machine_name")  ## for example: "ubuntu"
# If you want to run it normally:
proc = machine.launch_vm_process(session, "gui")
# If you want to run it in background:
# proc = machine.launch_vm_process(session, "headless")
proc.wait_for_completion(timeout=-1)
```